# Search for matching objects in a list and assign values

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, search

My class

```
class student   
{
    public string studentid { get; set; }
    public string groupid { get; set; }//Group id
}
```

My List

```
List<student> pupils = new List<student>();
```

here I select students with no group id

```
var studentsWithNoGroupId = from student in pupils
                            where student.groupid =="00"
                            select student;
```

I want to go through a for loop which runs number of times equal to studentsWithNoGroupId.Count and assign the group ids with some values I have. (Just showing how to assign each object will be enough). 
How to do that?

Or do I have to change my linq for that?
Please somebody help me.

Comment: You don't need the `where` just select, if the student has correct id, just return the student, if not, return a new student with the modified id (But then this returns the fact that linq is a query language and you'd probably be better off just writing with a normal foreach)

Comment: The values where are located? How you want assign these to the groupsid?

Comment: @Sayse
No I have assigned students with no group ids as "00" that's why I check for it..
How to do that any code examples..?

Comment: @Tinwor
I have max group id variable I plan to assign each group id with incrementing it..
That's why I need to do with a for loop..

Comment: I misread the question then.. where are the values coming from? another list somewhere?

Comment: @Sayse No No the values are originally from pupils list..

Comment: I mean for the group ids.. it could improve the quality of any answers given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     pupils.Where(p => p.groupid == "00")
      .ToList()
      .ForEach( 
         p => {
                p.groupid = "whatever";
         });
```

**EDIT**(after Hatsjoem hint, even more simple):

```
pupils.FindAll(p => p.groupid == "00")
 .ForEach(p => {
    p.groupid = "whatever";
 });
```

Comment: 1. ForEach linq is ugly and 2. this isn't LinqToSql

Comment: If you use `FindAll` instead of `Where` you don't need to call the `ToList` method, since it already returns a list.

Comment: @Sayse: beauty is subjective

Comment: LinQ is a query tool, and the way in which foreach linq is used for the majority of the time is adverse to this effect

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
var studentsWithNoGroupId = 
from student in pupils
where student.groupid =="00"
select student;

foreach(var student in studentsWithNoGroupId)
{
  student.groupid = "x";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think so.. I might sound stupid. I don't have much knowledge in linq.  But does this loop runs till the number of objects studentsWithNoGroupID ? Thanks for help. And I I want to get the count of studentsWithNoGroupId how to do that..?

Comment: If I'm correct you can't assign a value in `foreach` loop.

Comment: You can't change the student to a new object. Changing its properties should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
var studentsWithNoGroupId = from student in pupils
                            where student.groupid =="00"
                            select student;
```

creates a Linq query. This query does not execute immediately. To execute it, try the following:

```
var studentsWithNoGroupIdQuery = from student in pupils
                                 where student.groupid =="00"
                                 select student;

var studentsWithNoGroupId = studentsWithNoGroupIdQuery.ToList();

foreach (var student in studentsWithNoGroupId)
{
    student.groupid = // Your logic here.
}

// Save pupils back to the database here.
```

The ToList() causes the query to execute and store the results in a `List<student>`. It is important to execute the query before the iteration, because you are changing the same variable `groupid` on which the query is being filtered.

Comment: How to get the object count of studentsWithNoGroupId to a int variable? I need that count to decide some other fact. How to do that. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3572467 Use `studentsWithNoGroupId.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but I will give it a try:

```
var yourPupils = pupils.Where(p => p.groupid == "00")
    .Select(s => new student() { 
        studentid = s.studentid, 
        groupid = "yourCustomAssignedId" 
    }).ToList();
```

For-loop version:

```
var numberOfPupils = pupils.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPupils; i++)
{
    if (pupils[i].groupid == "00")
    {
        pupils[i].groupid = "yourCustomAssignedId";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It would be great if you can do it with a for loop.  and If I can get the count of yourPupils to a variable.

Comment: Is this a requirement to do this in a `loop`? If not then I personally think that this approach is better.